# Leaflet Draw: how localize into language other than English?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, localization, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm newbie in web development...

I work on Ruby on Rails project. How I can localize Leaflet Draw map into language other than English? Standart way (like for Rails views) doesn't work (I mean .yml files in config/locales/ folder).

This is my code for Leaflet Draw map: https://gist.github.com/Sontsevolosa/a10592f2172ea9c6fcd67c9c9d7569be

A lot of thanks for your help :)